# VbScript to find the end character of a string

Tags: vbscript

suppose there is a string like "thisisatextfilea.txt" . I have to trim the .txt and find if the remaining string(thisisatextfilea) ends with character a . Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please do your homework yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Split() to get the part before the . and Right() to get its tail:

```
>> s = "thisisatextfilea.txt"
>> WScript.Echo Right(Split(s, ".")(0), 1)
>>
a
```

(Checking your assumptions (there is a substring left of the one and only .) might be a good idea for production code.)

Comment: @Krishna, if your string is really a file name/path that may contain a period (in addition to the one used for the extension), you can use the `GetBaseName()` function of the `FileSystemObject` class to return the filename string minus the extension. `objFSO.GetBaseName("c:\some path\thisisatextfilea.txt")` would return just the string `thisisatextfilea`. Then, as Ekkehard has shown, use `Right()` to extract the rightmost character.